# No getting the option Create Pull Request in GitHub

Tags: git, github

[image]https://github.com/ChinmoyJana14/DataDriverFramework/compare/read-from-excel?expand=1

No getting the option Create Pull Request in GitHub

I have tried to create a branch from main branch

Answer (score 0):

The page displays:

> main and read-from-excel are entirely different commit histories.

That means they have no common history, no common ancestor commit from which one was created from the other.
It is as if `read-from-excel` is an orphan branch, created with `git switch --orphan`.

That would explain why there is no pull request possible.

One possible option is to [root rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---root) `read-from-excel` on top of `main`, and force push it.
Then comparing the two would include a pull request option.

```
git pull
git switch read-from-excel
git rebase --root main
git push --force
```

Comment: Tried but showing
C:\Repository\SeleniumJava\DataDrivenFramework>git rebase --root main

fatal: fatal: no such branch/commit 'main'  but I have the main branch only

Comment: @ChinmoyJ What does `git branch -avv` return?